# Access Violation - Execution of Address

Tags: delphi, access-violation, delphi-10-seattle

I'm been asked to investigate an access violation which has been occurring in our program, I have very little information to work off.

Here is the access violation

```
Access violation at address BC004DC2. Execution of address BC004DC2
```

I was wondering if anyone could provide information about this type of access violation, specifically the 'Execution of address' part.

Since it isn't

```
Access violation at address XXXX in module 'YYYY.exe'. Read of Address ZZZZ
```

I don't know what kind of things I should be looking for.

Comment: Sometimes in the debugger i step over code in a not initialized object. If the access violation ocurrs inside a class operation, try to inspect "self" just before the line that cause the error.

Comment: I would imagine that would raise a 'Read of address XXXX' violation and not an 'Execution of address XXXX' violation, but for completeness I'll perform a test, thanks

Comment: If the address is valid and ASLR is not enabled you could take a dump of a running application and look what code is running at `BC004DC2` with Windbg (`ln BC004DC2`) but probably easier woud be to either run the application under a debugger or use procmon to have it monitor first chance exceptions on your application *(and create a dumpfile to analyze)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that the instruction pointer is at an address that does not have `PAGE_EXECUTE` protection. That is typically because you are attempting to execute data.

This sort of error occurs most commonly with memory corruptions. You have corrupted either the heap or the stack. Or you are using a stale pointer to memory that has been freed, and then re-used by some other code.

Debug this by looking at the call stack and working out how you reached this point of execution. Whatever data structure contained the address that you are executing is invalid. Then trace back to see how it can be valid.

Comment: Thanks @David, now I have an understanding of the problem